# Cannot resolve Observable.zip method with function4

Tags: android, observable, rx-java2

I would like to handle multiple retrofit calls in once and for the task i'm using rxjava2. But i get cannot resolve method Observable.zip, probably it's a very trivial mistake but i can't get trough it, i know it would be resolved with lambda expression too, but i want to learn how to make it work without it.

```
Single<List<A>> observableA;
Single<List<B>> observableB;
Single<List<C>> observableC;
Single<List<D>> observableD;

listA = retofitCall(); 
// ....

io.reactivex.Observable.zip(observableA, observableB, observableC, observableD, new Function4<List<A>, List<B>, List<C>, List<D>, Bundle>() {
        @Override
        public Bundle apply(List<A> listA, List<B> listB, List<C> listC, List<D> listD) throws Exception {
            return new Bundle(listA,listB,listC,listD);
        }
    });
```

Bundle object:

```
public class Bundle {
List<A> listA ;
List<B> listB ;
List<C> listC ;
List<D> listD ;

public Bundle(List<A> listA, List<B> listB, List<C> listC, List<D> listD) {
    this.listA = listA;
    this.listB = listB;
    this.listC = listC;
    this.listD = listD;
 }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: As long as you don't subscribe, nothing will happen

Comment: the problem is not the subscribing, the problem is that i get a compile time error on Observable.zip stating i cannot resolve the zip method. Thanks anyway for the input :)

Comment: You need `Single.zip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that i should have used Single.zip instead of Observable.zip